# Mount and merge folder contents

Tags: mount, merge

Is there any way to mount a folder content inside to another one?

Let's say I have 2 folders with following content;

```
Folder1       Folder2
  file1       file2
```

I basically want to make visible all of the content of Folder2 in Folder1.  So the new content should be like this;

```
Folder1       Folder2
  file1       file2
  file2
```

And I also want Folder1 content to be updated when I do any change in Folder2. Let's say I've created file3 in Folder2. I'm expecting to see the new file under both of them.

```
Folder1       Folder2
  file1       file2
  file2       file3
  file3
```

So the general rules should be;

- If you create/delete/modify any file under Folder2, it will be also visible under Folder1.
- If you create/delete/modify any file in Folder 1 (which belongs to Folder2, for example removing file2), those changes will be done in Folder2.
- User should not see any content of Folder1 under Folder2.

Any solution for that kind of requirement?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would one want to do this? It looks messy.

Comment: For upstart conf files. I want to keep /etc/init tidy, so if I can do it, Folder1 will be /etc/init, and Folder2 will be my own service file folder which can reside anywhere in the system.

Answer (score 2):

Try use [overlayfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt)

```
mount -t overlay overlay Folder1 -o index=off,workdir=$(mktemp -d),upperdir=Folder2,lowerdir=Folder1
```

All files changes will visible under Folder1 and Folder2.
But if you change Folder1 origin files (example file1), changes will visible on Folder2 too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anyway to directly do what you're asking, and you would of course encounter issues if `file1` existed in both `folder1` and `folder2`.

You could create links from each file/directory under `folder2` to `folder1`, this would require a link per file/directory under `folder2`. You could create a script to keep the links updated and remove dead links.

If you used hard links then this would all be seamless when doing a directory listing etc.

You could then use `inotify` to watch `folder1` and `folder2` to trigger the creation/deletion of the hard links.

Comment: Creating another controller service is what I'm trying to escape, such as writing script. If I can mount the content of the folder2 into the folder1, and make it permanent, then there won't be any necessity to create a control mechanism.